# Windows 2008R2 smtp traffic cannot leave the box

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008

I have a weird situation where an Orion NPM server on a Windows 2008R2 box cannot connect to the mail server in our environment. The application logs show that it is indeed trying to connect but fails; however, a wireshark packet capture does not show any SMTP traffic leaving the system, no RSTs or anything, just blank. It is able to see all other traffic so it is sniffing traffic properly but i'm at a loss as to what could be blocking it. Windows firewall is completely off and disabled. The antivirus does not have a firewall extension/component to it. Even trying to telnet to port 25 on the destination fails. We're thinking that it's not an application issue because a different Orion server with the same app configuration is able to connect and we are able to see the traffic in wireshark.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Check the **"mail server in your environment"** to get the SMTP engine or whatever listening on it's side first. Oh and **" Even trying to telnet to port 25 on the destination fails"** then definitely start with the SMTP server and get it working first. Be sure to check the differences in subnets where it works and doesn't work too in case that matters in your case. Don't overlook a network adapter IPV6 versus IPV4 issue with DNS too so compare those TCP/IP settings where it works versus where it does not.

Comment: The mail server is a Postfix server with the whole /16 network whitelisted and has been in production for some time; it receives and processes transactions from other servers in the network just fine. I can hit Postfix from my workstation just fine also. The crux of the inquiry is that we're trying to determine why Wireshark is unable to pick up any smtp traffic. Admittedly this is an inherited environment and i'm actually a Linux guy; I'm not sure what mechanisms Windows has that would discriminate against a particular type of traffic like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary team found out that McAfee was running on the box and blocking the traffic despite Mcafee support telling them there was no firewall component to it.